# (Blockchain.py) The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

I'm trying to add a new transaction to my blockchain via a request method and I keep getting the error in the title.

Here's my request:

```
import requests
import json

data = {"sender" : "0", "recipient" : "x", "amount" : 10}

response = requests.post("http://localhost:5000/transactions/new", data=data).text
```

Here's where I'm interacting:

```
@app.route("/transactions/new", methods=["POST"])
def new_transaction():
    values = request.get_json(force=True)

    required = ["sender", "recipient", "amount"]
    if not all(k in values for k in required):
        return "Missing values", 400

    index = blockchain.new_transaction(values["sender"], values["recipient"], values["amount"])

    response = {"message": f"Transaction will be added too Block {index}"}
    return response, 201
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would call your flask app using `requests.post("http://localhost:5000/transactions/new", json=data)` which is more consistent with what you're doing. Can you post the actual error?

Comment: Hi, thanks adding json worked

Comment: Please add some background info about what frameworks you are using and add appropriate tags. It would also help to point out the exact line where the error occurs.